# Application Crahses in IE 6.. (c0000005 - access violation Error)

Tags: internet-explorer

I have got a serious problem running our web app in some machines.. machines installed IE 6 crahsed viewing particular page(even before page is started loading). But this works fine on all the machines installed IE 7 & IE 8.

I have created the crash dumb using the dr watson utility.. it logs the following error msg.
seems there is access violation happened in mshtml.dll.. but i dont know whether this is happened because of our page or some other thing.. can someone help me out to resplve this one..

if u go through the stack trace below, u could see this line

```
FAULT ->7dcb1227 f3a6             rep     cmpsb         ds:044ae560=00 es:00000000=??
```

this is where exactly the error happened..  but i dont know how to use this line to identify the actual problem... :(

```
Application exception occurred:
        App: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe (pid=3780)
        When: 8/12/2009 @ 10:53:34.796
        Exception number: c0000005 (access violation)



*----> State Dump for Thread Id 0x8ec <----*

eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=000000bc edx=044ae560 esi=044ae560 edi=00000000
eip=7dcb1227 esp=044ae1b8 ebp=044ae1c4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246

function: mshtml
        7dcb1213 ec               in      al,dx
        7dcb1214 53               push    ebx
        7dcb1215 8b5d08           mov     ebx,[ebp+0x8]
        7dcb1218 56               push    esi
        7dcb1219 8bd1             mov     edx,ecx
        7dcb121b 57               push    edi
        7dcb121c b9bc000000       mov     ecx,0xbc
        7dcb1221 8bfb             mov     edi,ebx
        7dcb1223 8bf2             mov     esi,edx
        7dcb1225 33c0             xor     eax,eax
FAULT ->7dcb1227 f3a6             rep     cmpsb         ds:044ae560=00 es:00000000=??
        7dcb1229 7405             jz      mshtml+0x81230 (7dcb1230)
        7dcb122b 1bc0             sbb     eax,eax
        7dcb122d 83d8ff           sbb     eax,0xffffffff
        7dcb1230 85c0             test    eax,eax
        7dcb1232 74b6             jz      mshtml+0x811ea (7dcb11ea)
        7dcb1234 33c9             xor     ecx,ecx
        7dcb1236 85c0             test    eax,eax
        7dcb1238 0f94c1           sete    cl
        7dcb123b 5f               pop     edi
        7dcb123c 5e               pop     esi

*----> Stack Back Trace <----*
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
044ae1c4 7dcafe25 00000000 044ae1e4 7dd22e8e mshtml+0x81227
044ae1d0 7dd22e8e 044ae560 00000000 01b6ce84 mshtml+0x7fe25
044ae1e4 7dc9ac9b 01b6ce80 044ae560 000001f8 mshtml!DllGetClassObject+0x4e82
044ae1f8 7dcb4105 075573f0 000003f0 044ae560 mshtml+0x6ac9b
044ae21c 7dd243fe 000003f0 044ae560 044ae240 mshtml+0x84105
044ae244 7dc9d2c6 044ae560 01b6bb50 044ae3c0 mshtml!DllGetClassObject+0x63f2
044ae25c 7dcb0ef6 044ae560 044ae290 00000000 mshtml+0x6d2c6
044ae294 7dcb2ece 044ae3c0 01c7a3e0 01c7a820 mshtml+0x80ef6
044ae2d0 7dcb1d8a ffffffff 01c7a820 01c7a820 mshtml+0x82ece
044ae2ec 7dcb08d7 044ae3c0 01c7a820 01defeb0 mshtml+0x81d8a
044ae330 7dcb1d8a 01c7a820 01defed0 01defed0 mshtml+0x808d7
044ae34c 7dcb08d7 044ae3c0 01defed0 01e10f60 mshtml+0x81d8a
044ae390 7dcb1d8a 01defed0 01e101a0 01e10f60 mshtml+0x808d7
044ae3ac 7dcd5962 044ae3c0 01e101a0 01e101a0 mshtml+0x81d8a
044ae630 7dcd9925 01ddad60 7dcea557 01ddad20 mshtml+0xa5962
044ae664 7dcefcb6 00000000 01ddad20 044ae6ec mshtml+0xa9925
044ae694 7dca9cf5 044ae6ec 01ddad20 044ae6ec mshtml+0xbfcb6
044ae6ac 7dcd6306 01ddad20 044ae6ec 00000001 mshtml+0x79cf5
044ae6c8 7dca1acb 044ae6ec 0000001b 00000001 mshtml+0xa6306
044ae728 7dc99875 044ae7b4 0024efb0 044ae7b4 mshtml+0x71acb
044ae784 7dc9a93a 01e10f60 0024f070 01c7a470 mshtml+0x69875
044ae7a0 7dca337f 044ae7b4 01ddad60 01e10f60 mshtml+0x6a93a
044ae7ec 7dca3338 00000006 00020000 00000000 mshtml+0x7337f
044ae80c 7dca7ac0 00020000 01e10f60 01db1390 mshtml+0x73338
044ae828 7dca0fa9 044ae840 00000000 00000001 mshtml+0x77ac0
044ae880 7dca1052 058c1cf3 01db1f70 00000000 mshtml+0x70fa9
01db1680 01c7a470 00000000 00000000 0024efb0 mshtml+0x71052
01e10530 01e104e0 ffff021e ffffffff 00000061 0x1c7a470
01e10510 00000001 00000008 00000000 01e10530 0x1e104e0

*----> Raw Stack Dump <----*
00000000044ae1b8  f0 73 55 07 88 91 50 07 - 49 02 00 00 d0 e1 4a 04  .sU...P.I.....J.
00000000044ae1c8  25 fe ca 7d 00 00 00 00 - e4 e1 4a 04 8e 2e d2 7d  %..}......J....}
00000000044ae1d8  60 e5 4a 04 00 00 00 00 - 84 ce b6 01 f8 e1 4a 04  `.J...........J.
00000000044ae1e8  9b ac c9 7d 80 ce b6 01 - 60 e5 4a 04 f8 01 00 00  ...}....`.J.....
00000000044ae1f8  1c e2 4a 04 05 41 cb 7d - f0 73 55 07 f0 03 00 00  ..J..A.}.sU.....
00000000044ae208  60 e5 4a 04 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 80 ce b6 01  `.J.............
00000000044ae218  fd 00 00 00 44 e2 4a 04 - fe 43 d2 7d f0 03 00 00  ....D.J..C.}....
00000000044ae228  60 e5 4a 04 40 e2 4a 04 - 00 00 00 00 80 ce b6 01  `.J.@.J.........
00000000044ae238  20 a8 c7 01 f0 03 00 00 - 80 ce b6 01 5c e2 4a 04   ...........\.J.
00000000044ae248  c6 d2 c9 7d 60 e5 4a 04 - 50 bb b6 01 c0 e3 4a 04  ...}`.J.P.....J.
00000000044ae258  80 ce b6 01 94 e2 4a 04 - f6 0e cb 7d 60 e5 4a 04  ......J....}`.J.
00000000044ae268  90 e2 4a 04 00 00 00 00 - 01 00 00 00 ff ff ff 00  ..J.............
00000000044ae278  c0 e3 4a 04 8c c1 b6 01 - ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ..J.............
00000000044ae288  ff ff ff ff 20 a8 c7 01 - 30 00 00 00 d0 e2 4a 04  .... ...0.....J.
00000000044ae298  ce 2e cb 7d c0 e3 4a 04 - e0 a3 c7 01 20 a8 c7 01  ...}..J..... ...
00000000044ae2a8  c0 e3 4a 04 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 70 a4 c7 01  ..J.........p...
00000000044ae2b8  b0 ef 24 00 00 00 00 00 - ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  ..$.............
00000000044ae2c8  01 00 00 00 e0 a3 c7 01 - ec e2 4a 04 8a 1d cb 7d  ..........J....}
00000000044ae2d8  ff ff ff ff 20 a8 c7 01 - 20 a8 c7 01 c0 e3 4a 04  .... ... .....J.
00000000044ae2e8  50 bb b6 01 30 e3 4a 04 - d7 08 cb 7d c0 e3 4a 04  P...0.J....}..J.
```

**EDIT::**

here the Watson Bucket number

```
Fault bucket 1229674410.
```

and some msgs in system logs

```
The application, C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe, generated an application error The error occurred on 08/14/2009 @ 10:32:36.617 The exception generated was c0000005 at address 7DCB1227 (mshtml)

Faulting application iexplore.exe, version 6.0.2900.2180, faulting module mshtml.dll, version 6.0.2900.3527, fault address 0x00081227.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, i finally nailed down this problem.. After painful debugging for several hours andi steped in the code where the problem originates..

In simple terms **"IE 6 crashes on multiple re-arrangements (like during on resize) of ui elements on a page load"**

Please go through the below paragraph if you wanted to know more about this. Our page is composed of multiple views of grids and other complex controls and  maintained within several iframes under single master page(not aspx master page). And this one is responsible for rearranging (like re-render the positions during the resizes) the UI elemnts in a master layout level if there is any change in other frame sets.

And in particular page we just made a change to accomodate more than one grid views, and the size of the view is hardcoded in javascript (this is done in body onload of the form) based on the screen resolution (this is the real culprit). this triggers the chain of obresize events and routed to the matser page. First resize is working fine and any other sequence of this event led the IE to crash.

I know this is weird but this works perfectly after removing that manual size setting code...

Answer (score 0):

In your system event log, you should see a Watson "Bucket number."  If you mail that to me (ericlaw @ microsoft) I can take a look to see what the root cause of the problem is.

Comment: thanks for the reply Eric.. i just sent u the mail with all the necessary info.. this is the msg recorded in system log "Fault bucket 1229674410."..